# passing data from js file to php using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**ajaxcheck.js**

```
var val = "hai";

 $.ajax(
 {
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'ajaxphp.php',
 data: { "abc" : val },

success :function(data)
 {
    alert('success'); 
 }

 }

 )
.done(function(data) { 
alert("success :"+data.slice(0, 100));

 }

 )
.fail(function() { 

alert("error"); 

}
);
```

**ajax.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html >

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
 </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxcheck.js"></script>

  <title>ajax request testing</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**ajaxphp.php**

```
<?php

$v_var = $_POST["abc"];

print_r($_POST);

if(isset($_POST["abc"]))
{
echo $v_var;
}
else
{
echo "Data not received";
}
?>
```

When I run the ajax.html file ,I get success alert. But when I run ajaxphp.php file it shows  notice like:

```
undefined index abc
```

Why is that the data is not received in `$v_var` ? where i am mistaking ?please help.

Comment: I think your new to php. First read php manuals clearly .

Answer (score 0):

> Actually the ajaxphp.php file is used to receive the data from the
>   post method and i will give  response .

In First case by using ajax post method it will call to ajaxphp.php file.

In Second case your using direct file call without any post data(that's way it shows error)

Try this

var val = "hai"
    $.post( "ajaxphp.php", {'abc':val}function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });

Comment: ,without any post data ?? the ajax call in ajaxcheck.js does post data which is "hai" to ajaxphp.php file right ?then why ajaxphp.php  does not receive that data in the variable and print it ?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery expects an object as data, remove the double-quotes:

```
data: { abc : val }
```

Comment: Is your php filename is correct? You have "ajaxphpcheck.php" in js and  "ajaxphp.php" in your post.

Comment: ya the file name is correct only ,sorry i forgot to make the editing to ajaxphp.php in js while posting ..